# Генерация классов в С++ из PostgreSQL

Tags: c++, база-данных, postgresql, классы

Добрый день,

такая задача, сделать генератор классов из PostgreSQL, а если быть точным, то перенести с Firebird на PostgreSQL. Исходники то у меня имеются, только не имею ни малейшего понятия, как это сделать.

Прошу вашей помощи, желательно описать алгоритм или описать логику того, что мне предстоит сделать, или подкиньте ссылочку, где описано, что-то похожее, так как ничего сам нужного не нашёл.

Comment: для начала Вам нужно понять, что этот генератор классов реально генерирует.

Comment: я просматривал, значит он генеринует интерфейс для мапера, для репазитория, базовый класс, класс для маппера и репазитория, какие-то файлы с bill в названии. Ну при создании  самих классов, создаются в частности хедеры и ссp-файлы

Comment: Обычно для подключения к СУБД используются "драйверы" баз данных. Какой всётаки интерфейс (драйвер) используется для подключения? Native(fbclient.dll)? Ado? ISQLConnection?  OleDB? Поняв какой драйвер - будет понятно как переключить.

Comment: для подключения будет использован pqxx

Comment: pqxx  - это подключение к postgree, а чем подключаетесть к FireBird? И что имеете ввиду Генерация классов"? Может два куска кода покажете, как на fb и как на pg?

Comment: @nick_n_a , извиняюсь, что не отвечал, на Firebird был использован ibpp, сейчас использую, как уже говорил pqxx, [тут код](http://pastebin.com/utrWb4Cp) собственно, который нужно перевести на pqxx. Вот не очень понимаю, что там происходит((

Comment: У вас использованы "кодозависимые" таблицы,  RDB$FIELDS   например. Боюсь вам прийдётся переписывать "с ноля".

Comment: @nick_n_a , ок, тогда вопросик, таблицы нужно по новой создавать тоже? и как я понимаю нужно их создавать в PgManager? А так же, не могли бы пояснить, что происходит вообще, так как я случайно принялся за проект и всё для меня в новинку.

Comment: Подключения к СУБД бывает "общее" наприме ODBC или OleDB, и найтивное. Для нейтивного под каждый найтив нужно писать свои процедуры. Для общего пользуетесь общим интерфейсом и всё. Так как вы выбрали native - то вам прийдётся всё переписывать. Таблицы можно создать SQL-запросами. Если у вас винда - найдите ODBCViewer или что-то такое. Например http://www.ex.ua/89640852 и сможете просмотреть базу или сделать запросы.

Comment: Для fb хорошо подходит IBExpert http://www.ex.ua/6494084. Ещё, Классы pg можно взять с папки include и там source или demo с папки в которую установлен клиент PG. FB - аналогично.

Comment: @nick_n_a, а что "fb" значит? а так же не мог ли бы взглянуть на код и объяснить что выполняется(если вас не затруднит), так как я понял, сначала создаём базу данных, потом подключаем её, делаем транзакцию( поясните что это за процесс), делаем какой-то стейтмент(что это?), считываем sql запрос а потом творится что-то непонятное...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44192/discussion-between-koshachok-and-nick-n-a).